# Module has no attribute error in python3

Tags: python, class

contents of `io.py`

```
class IO:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ParsingFile = '../list'

    def Parser(self):
        f = open(ParsingFile, 'r')
        print(f.read())
```

contents of `main.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "lib/")

try:
    import io
except Exception:
    print("Could not import one or more libraries.")
    exit(1)

print("Libraries imported")
_io_ = io.IO()
```

When I run `python3 main.py` I get the following error:

```
Libraries imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    _io_ = io.IO()
AttributeError: module 'io' has no attribute 'IO'
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My file was called `io`. It seems that there already exists a package called `io` which caused the confusion.

Comment: ah, that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Your package name (io) conflicts with the Python library's package with the same name, so you actually import a system package.

You can check this by printing `io.__all__`.

Changing io.py to something else is probably the best way to go to avoid similar problems. Otherwise, you can use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from io import IO
```

That worked for me when trying to import classes from another file

this has more information:

[Python module import - why are components only available when explicitly imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876962/python-module-import-why-are-components-only-available-when-explicitly-importe)